# JavaScript map object type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I encountered following declaration in typescript Corday:

books : { [isbn:string]:Book}={};

I am assuming that this could be definition of a map (I.e. dictionary) data type that stores key value pair of isbn number and corresponding book.

What I am not able to understand is the declaration syntax.  How is this supposed to represent a map declaration?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a "map" declaration, it's an object declaration. This:

```
books: { [isbn: string]: Book } = {};
```

Means that `books` is an object, with a key named `isbn` (which is a string), that has a value of type `Book`.

Comment: "with a key named isbn" --- it's an oddity of typescript object key type declaration, but `isbn` means nothing there, it might be anything. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types